# How to remove ripples in a square pulse generated by Fourier Series using a filter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Here is my code that generates the square pulse signal with Fourier Series.

```
clear; close all; clc;

high = 5;
low = 5;
amp = 1;
f = 1/(high + low)*100;
T = 1/f;
duty = high/(high+low) * 100;
fs = 100*f;
duration = 5*T;
N = duration * fs;
t = linspace (0,duration-1/fs,N);
v = 0;

y = amp*square (2*pi*f*t,duty) + v;
A = max(y);
B = min(y);

Tp = duty/100 * T;
a0 = (A-B)*Tp/T + B;
x = a0;

H = 1:5;     
for i = 1:length(H)       
    an = (A-B)/(pi*H(i)) * sin(2*pi*f*Tp*H(i));       
    bn = (A-B)/(pi*H(i)) * (1-cos(2*pi*f*Tp*H(i)));       
    x = x + an * cos(2*pi*f*t*H(i)) + bn * sin(2*pi*f*t*H(i));        
end

hold on
plot (t,x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) you will not be able to get rid of the ripples.

To reduce them, or to get closer to a square, you need to sum more components from your infinite Fourier series.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help Mr. Stack. But actually, I need to reduce them by using a filter, because this is a requirement in my DSP course project. One of the professors suggested that we can use a Band-stop (Band-reject) filter to at least reduce these ripples, but unfortunately I do not how to build up a filter to use it for ripples reduction.

Comment: A linear filter will either not get rid of all the ripples, or make the resulting waveform no longer square (closer to a triangle wave or trapezoid).